# Clean up user generated times in a cell to proper hh:mm format Macro

Tags: excel, vba, time, format

I've been handed a sheet with a large column of times that are a complete mess, and will continue to be as it's user generated from another program.  Examples..

```
1245-245
1-3
12-2:30
900-1
```

These are all in a range down a single column.

I've tried isolating the number prior to the "-" and then also the numbers after to try and clean up but just wondering if I'm thinking about his all wrong and there is an easier way to do so...

We need to have all 4 digit time on both sides of the "-" so no matter what is entered would display standard hh:mm time frame

Comment: Control data entry with a user form

Comment: `=REPLACE(LEFT(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1),":",""),REPT("0",IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1),":",""))<=2,2,4)))&"00",4),3,0,":")&"-"&REPLACE(LEFT(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),":",""),REPT("0",IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),":",""))<=2,2,4)))&"00",4),3,0,":")`

Comment: That formula works, thank you!

Comment: is it possible to keep in same column as the data, and if blank fill with T.B.A.?